# Trouble Clicking on Link

Tags: java, selenium

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHEQ0.png

The above shows the source and the blue highlighted is the button I want to click on.

I tried a few things like

WebElement element = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*                                 [@id=\"PatientHome\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/a"));

EDIT:
   WebManager.driver.switchTo().frame("EMGuildline");
WebManager.driver.switchTo().frame("EMGuildlineWin");

Tried both and still can't click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the element you want to click is in an `iframe`.  Selenium can only access content in an `iframe` or `frame` if you switch into that context.

You'll need to switch into the `iframe`:

```
webdriver.switchTo().frame("EMGuildlineWin");
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//* [@id='PatientHome']/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/a")).click();
```

When you're done in the `iframe`, you'll need to switch back out:

```
webdriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

`switchTo()` accepts several arguments
- id or name - `id="EMGuildlineWin"` means you can use `switchTo().frame("EMGuildlineWin")`
- index - zero based - `switchTo().frame(0)`
- webElement - using `findElement`, you can pass the result - `switchTo.frame(webdriver.findElement(ByLocator))`